# Visual studio cannot locate XML file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm attempting to develop a Windows 7 Phone and I am using an XML file that I need to parse and then perform a Linq query on.

The problem is this:

Whenever I try to access the file (it is stored locally) it brings back an error saying the file cannot be found as it's not part of the XAP package.

I have tried another solution where I use `StreamReader` But I am still getting a simular error:

> Attempt to access the method failed System.IO.File.OpenText(System.String)

Here is the code that I am using:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:/Users/Desktop/Assign/obj/Debug/buildings.kml"))
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load ("buildings.kml");
            XNamespace kml = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

            var dict = xdoc.Descendants(kml + "Placemark")
                          .ToDictionary(d => d.Element(kml + "name").Value,
                          d => d.Element(kml + "id").Value);

            foreach (var b in dict) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Building Name -> " + b.Key + " Building ID -> " + b.Value);
            }
        }
```

The file is located in: > C:/Users/Desktop/Assign/obj/Debug/buildings.kml so I cannot see the problem. Outside of Visual Studio, I can read in the .xml file fine.

Hope someone can help

EDIT:

New code -

```
Dictionary<string, string> getBuildingNames()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(@"Data\mydata.kml", UriKind.Relative);

        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sri.Stream);

        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
        XNamespace kml = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

        var dict = xdoc.Descendants(kml + "Placemark")
                      .ToDictionary(d => d.Element(kml + "name").Value,
                      d => d.Element(kml + "id").Value);


        return dict;


    }
```

Error: - 'NullReferenceException was unhanded'

Comment: try using C://Users//Desktop//Assign//obj//Debug//buildings.kml

Comment: Is this meant to be executing in a WP7 app? If so, I can't see how it could possibly work... it's not like you've got that directory in WP7, is it? Please clarify the question.

Comment: Check File.Exists(path) first. perhaps it will give you a hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you really are trying to do this as part of a WP7 project (rather than some non-mobile project related to it, e.g. preprocessing) you shouldn't be using `File.OpenText`.

Options:

- Include the XML in your XAP file, and read from that using [`Application.GetResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190632%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (see this [blog post for details](http://www.steveives.com/2011/11/reading-files-from-a-windows-phone-xap-file/))
- Somehow get the XML into isolated storage, and use the [isolated storage API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- Embed the resource into your assembly, and use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: If I used the solution (in the blog) Would I have to use 'XDocument.Parse' instead of 'XDocument.Load'?

Comment: @Phorce: No, it still gets a stream - so use `XDocument.Load(Stream)`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a go when I'm back into our labs. Hopefully, this will work. I didn't think it would be this complex using WP7

Comment: @Phorce: Well did you really think your device would have a "C:/Users/Desktop/Assign/obj/Debug" directory?

Comment: No, of course not! I was just testing it, I thought I could have a Current.Directory() function (or something). Ah thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hey, I have updated my post because I have a new error with the StreamReader. Please could you look where I am going wrong? The file does exist within the project. Thank you

Comment: @Phorce: Check whether `sri` is null. I suspect that even if the file exists in the project, it may not be set to be an appropriate resource.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of some more tips to help you along:

1) Change the Build action property of the xml file to "Content". (Select the file and go to the properties window in Visual Studio)

2) If you only want to read from the file, then there is no need to have the file in IsolatedStorage. You can simply read it if you correctly set the Build Action property.

You can use XDocument to read the file.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
```

where *filepath* is simply the relative path to the XML file, i.e. if you did not place it inside any folder in your project then it will be just the file name (assume it like being the root directory)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The thing is, I do not know how to change the "Build action" property of the xml file..

Comment: Add the file to your visual studio project. Go to View->Properties Window. Then select the XML file (from the solution explorer) and then in the Properties Window you should see Build Action.

Comment: Thank you :)! I will test this again when I am next in my lab, but, thanks!